# How can I connect to my Apache 2 web site that sits on the Ubuntu Server through IP?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

Here's my virtual host configurations:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abwebserver
    ServerAdmin <my e-mail>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?abwiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm to trying connect to my web site from the other Windows 10 machine that's on the network like this:

```
http://<IP address>/abwiki/
```

but it doesn't work.

If I go to `http://<IP address>` I can see the Apache 2 Default Page.

If I put `<IP address> abwebserver` to the *hosts* file then it works.

What changes should I make to my configuration file in order to be able to connect to the web site through the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Beause the ServerName element restricts what hosts are permitted to access this virtual host. Having a website directly on an IP is not usually recommended partly because it normally prevents the use of https but also prevents hosting multiple "virtual" hosts on the same server.

Comment: And still, how can I connect to my web site through the IP? How should I change my virtual host configuration file in order to allow this to happen?

Comment: You should ask a different question or add an edit to the question above since I have answered the question you asked. You need to explain why you need to match both ip and hostname so that someone can offer the best way to achieve it since there is usually more than one way.

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Port 80
Listen 111.22.33.44:80
ServerName server.domain.tld

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44:80>
ServerName abwebserver
ServerAdmin <my e-mail>
DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?abwiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_error
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mediawiki_access common
</VirtualHost>
```

Have you tried the above? Where 111.22.33.44 is the ip you want access your site on.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Now it won't even load the Apache 2 Default Page.

Comment: I edited it, I forgot something. Run a apachectl configtest to test this @JConstantine

Comment: Syntax error on line 1:
Port was replaced with Listen in Apache 2.0
Ok. I deleted the "Port 80" line and now apachectl configtest says OK. But I can't start Apache 2 now.

Comment: And what is "server.domain.tld" ?

Comment: That should be the fully qualified domain name of your website, you can comment it out or remove if you don't have it, but it's common practice. Also for futher reference, if you need to restore a vhost from a backup you can identify which vhost is for which website

Comment: When I try to start Apache now it says:
Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address <IP>,
no listening sockets available, shutting down

Comment: Then you already have a process listening on port 80 which makes this impossible. Do a grep -r :80 in the /etc/apache to see what is listening

Comment: It's because I have "Listen 111.22.33.44:80" and <VirtualHost 111.22.33.44:80>.

Comment: The result of the grep -r :80
sites-available/000-default.conf:<VirtualHost *:80>
sites-available/mediawiki.conf:Listen <IP>:80
sites-available/mediawiki.conf:<VirtualHost <IP>:80>

Comment: Any other ideas?